# Webscraping with scrapy - how to interpret settings

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, settings

I am currently working on scraping company websites to a depth of 2. I have created a script that loops through a list of companies and their URLs given in an excel sheet and launches a CrawlSpyder for each company. In connection with this, I have unfortunately experienced that one of the companies complained about too much activity on their server - they experienced up to 8 hits per second for one site even though I thought that using AUTOTHROTTLE would be save enough. I have tried to investigate the matter regarding scrapy settings but still have a few (but critical) explanatory issues. My goal is to run an extremely safe/politely scraper that will never overload any server.

**My previous settings:**

AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True

RETRY_TIMES = 5

DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT = 10

ROBOTSTEXT_OBEY = True

COOKIES_ENABLED = False

DOWNLOAD_MAXSIZE = 100000

**The new settings I have added:**

CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PR_DOMAIN = 1
(I have an idea that the up to 8 hits per second was due to concurrent request per domain by default is 8)

DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 1

**This is how I understand Scrapy and its flow:**

[image: Scrapy request/response flow]

CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = Max number of requests that my own computer is handling simultaneously

CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = Max number of simultaneous requests that will be sent to one domain

DOWNLOAD_DELAY = Delay between each slot

AUTOTHROTTLE = Automatically adjusts the delay in relation to the individual servers. It acts “on top” of DOWLOAD_DELAY and thus it can only adjust the delay to be more than DOWNLOAD_DELAY and never less. Moreover it also adjust number of concurrent requests, but also here it is limited:  CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN is an upper limit.

Comment: What’s the question?

Comment: Is my understanding of the above settings correct? Am I guaranteed with my adjusted settings that I would not be able to overload any external server?

Comment: “Is my understanding of the above settings correct?” It seems so; do you have any reason to believe otherwise? “Am I guaranteed with my adjusted settings that I would not be able to overload any external server?” You are never guaranteed that you won’t overload a server. Your settings won’t overload some servers; for other servers, you might need an even higher download delay.